# Configuração do Jenkins com Nunit dando erro

Tags: c#, jenkins

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando configurar o jenkins para verificar os meus testes, porém está dando erro. Imagino que esteja fazendo alguma besteira que não estou percebendo, poderiam me ajudar?

Minha configuração do Comando do windows:

""C:\tools\bin\net35\nunit3-console.exe" "D:\Projetos\TARGETMP\jenkins-poc\projeto_teste\ByteBankTeste\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ByteBankTeste.dll" \ByteBankTeste.dll" /xml=nunit-result.xml"

E o erro do log é esse:

NUnit Console Runner 3.10.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2019 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
sexta-feira, 19 de julho de 2019 16:27:28

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    D:\Projetos\TARGETMP\jenkins-poc\projeto_teste\ByteBankTeste\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ByteBankTeste.dll
    \ByteBankTeste.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml

Errors, Failures and Warnings

1) Error : D:\Projetos\TARGETMP\jenkins-poc\projeto_teste\ByteBankTeste\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ByteBankTeste.dll
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : NÆo foi poss¡vel carregar arquivo ou assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' ou uma de suas dependˆncias. O sistema nÆo pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
--NUnitEngineException
An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.

Server stack trace: 
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\DirectTestRunner.cs:linha 168
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage() na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\DirectTestRunner.cs:linha 154
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded() na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\DirectTestRunner.cs:linha 268
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\DirectTestRunner.cs:linha 212
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   em NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)

### em NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\ProcessRunner.cs:linha 170

FileNotFoundException
NÆo foi poss¡vel carregar arquivo ou assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' ou uma de suas dependˆncias. O sistema nÆo pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
   em System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   em System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   em System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   em System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   em System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   em NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] args) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Drivers\NUnit3FrameworkDriver.cs:linha 171
   em NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(String testAssemblyPath, IDictionary`2 settings) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Drivers\NUnit3FrameworkDriver.cs:linha 84
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage) na C:\src\nunit\nunit-console\src\NUnitEngine\nunit.engine\Runners\DirectTestRunner.cs:linha 164

2) Invalid : C:\ByteBankTeste.dll\xml=nunit-result.xml
File not found: C:\ByteBankTeste.dll\xml=nunit-result.xml

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-07-19 19:27:29Z
    End time: 2019-07-19 19:27:32Z
    Duration: 3.298 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test_MsUnit>exit -100 
Build step 'Executar no comando do Windows' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigada!

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. The Language we use on Superuser is English, can you please [translate](https://superuser.com/posts/1461918/edit) your question so that everyone here can understand it?.

Answer (score 0):

O nunit console ainda não é compatível com .net core 2.1
Segue fonte:
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/392